# Why does my object increase and deform when i first select the object, then the armature and afterwards go to Set Parent With Automatic Weights?

Tags: rigging, armature, vertex-groups

Recently i've downloaded the Minecraft-Character-Rig from Rymdnisse, but i was a bit unsatisfied with the the backbone of the armature (it had altogether only 2 bones). At the beginning it wasn't possible for me to rotate the pelvis. But i was able to solve it. However, the upper body was affected too heavily, so i had to add another bone. So i selected the bone for the lower body in Edit-mode, pressed W and subdivided it once. Then i adjusted my modification (Clear Parent etc.) so that everything works fine.

But there was one problem. i had to adjust the weights for the three bones that had been affected by this modification, otherwise nothing would have been changed.
Therefore i first selected the object, then the armature and afterwards i selected with **ctrl + P** *Set Parent to / With Automatic Weights*, but there was a very strange result. The whole body was increased ~10 times, shifted a bit down and two places were completely deformed.

I also tried to use Set Parent to / *With Envelope Weights* or *With Empty Groups*, but the result remained the same. Even after i've deleted all Vertex Groups, Physics, Modifiers and Shape Keys, the result was still the same. So i conclude that there might be a problem with the object, but i'm not sure about it.

How am i able to solve this problem or are there any other options to adjust the Weights properly (but not manually since it's not very accurate)?

Here is the Minecraft-Rig i've used: https://rymdnisse.net/downloads.html (i've used this file: Minecraft_Character_Rig.blend )

[image]

This is the object with my modification (3 bones now).

[image]

Here is the object after i selected *Set Parent to...* (Head and armature remain in the same place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before parenting, apply the scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) to both your rig and your character.

Comment: Thank you, now it seems to work. But somehow the weight-distribution is a bit strange. Let's use for example the bone in the middle of the character. The strength in the middle of that bone is the highest, then decreases. It's like a circle. Was this to be expected? If yes, is there a possibility to copy the weights from another bone?